# Dropdown on hover is moving towards left of dropdown image in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, liferay-theme

I'm using jQuery for dropdown on hover in Liferay. The dropdown works absolutely fine when I run this jQuery as a separate HTML file, but if I use the same Jquery using the Liferay theme and add HTML in the web content section, the dropdown moves slightly to the left. Below is my CSS, HTML and jQuery code:

```js
/* Flex Level Drop Down Menu
* Created: Jan 5th, 2010 by DynamicDrive.com. This notice must stay intact for usage 
* Author: Dynamic Drive at http://www.dynamicdrive.com/
* Visit http://www.dynamicdrive.com/ for full source code
*/

//Version 1.1 (Feb 19th, 2010): Each flex menu (UL) can now be associated with a link dynamically, and/or defined using JavaScript instead of as markup.
//Version 1.2 (July 2nd, 2011): Menu updated to work properly in popular mobile devices such as iPad/iPhone and Android tablets.
//Version 1.3 (Nov 28th, 2011): Script now dynamically adds a class of "selected" to the anchor link while its drop down menu is expanded, for easy styling of the anchor link during its "open" state.
//Version 2.0 (April 16th, 2015): Adds mobile friendly, overlay version of the menu that's activated in mobile and small screen browsers. Refines drop down menu behavior when there's neither space to the right nor left to accommodate sub menu; in that case, sub menu overlaps parent menu. Requires jquery 1.8+

//Usage: $(elementselector).addflexmenu('menuid', options)
//ie:
//jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 //$('a.mylinks').addflexmenu('flexmenu1') //apply flex menu with ID "flexmenu1" to links with class="mylinks"
//})

jQuery.noConflict()

var flexdropdownmenu={
 arrowpath: 'arrow.gif', //full URL or path to right arrow image
 backarrowpath: 'left.gif', //full URL or path to back arrow image
 animspeed: 200, //reveal animation speed (in milliseconds)
 showhidedelay: [150, 150], //delay before menu appears and disappears when mouse rolls over it, in milliseconds
 mobilemediaquery: "screen and (max-width: 600px)", // CSS media query string that when matched activates mobile menu (while hiding default)

 //***** NO NEED TO EDIT BEYOND HERE
 mobilemql: null,
 startzindex:1000,
 mobilezindex: 1001,
 ismobile:navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad)|(iPhone)|(iPod)|(android)|(webOS)/i) != null, //boolean check for popular mobile browsers
 builtflexmenuids: [], //ids of flex menus already built (to prevent repeated building of same flex menu)
 ulclones: {}, // object holding clone of each drop down menu UL
 hidemenuevent: navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad)|(iPhone)|(iPod)/i)? 'touchstart' : 'click', // Mac doesn't seem to support click on body

 css3animation: (function(){ // check for CSS3 animation support
  var elstyle = document.createElement('p').style
  return 'animation' in elstyle || 'WebkitAnimation' in elstyle || 'MozAnimation' in elstyle
 })(),

 positionul:function($, $ul, e, $anchor){
  var istoplevel=$ul.hasClass('jqflexmenu') || $ul.hasClass('flexmenumobile') //Bool indicating whether $ul is top level flex menu or main mobile container
  var docrightedge=$(document).scrollLeft()+$(window).width()-40 //40 is to account for shadows in FF
  var docbottomedge=$(document).scrollTop()+$(window).height()-40
  if (istoplevel){ //if main flex menu DIV
   var offsets=$anchor.offset()
   var anchorsetting=this.mobilemql.matches? $anchor.data('mobilesetting') : $anchor.data('setting')
   var x=offsets.left+anchorsetting.useroffsets[0]+(anchorsetting.dir=="h"? $anchor.outerWidth() : 0) //x pos of main flex menu UL
   var y=offsets.top+anchorsetting.useroffsets[1]+(anchorsetting.dir=="h"? 0 : $anchor.outerHeight())
   x=(x+$ul.data('dimensions').w > docrightedge)? x-(anchorsetting.useroffsets[0]*2)-$ul.data('dimensions').w+$anchor.outerWidth()+(anchorsetting.dir=="h"? -($anchor.outerWidth()*2) : 0) : x //if not enough horizontal room to the ridge of the cursor
   y=(y+$ul.data('dimensions').h > docbottomedge)? y-(anchorsetting.useroffsets[1]*2)-$ul.data('dimensions').h-$anchor.outerHeight()+(anchorsetting.dir=="h"? ($anchor.outerHeight()*2) : 0) : y
  }
  else{ //if sub level flex menu UL
   var $parentli=$ul.data('$parentliref')
   var parentlioffset=$parentli.offset()
   var x=$ul.data('dimensions').parentliw //x pos of sub UL
   var y=0
   if ( (parentlioffset.left+x+$ul.data('dimensions').w) > docrightedge ){ //if not enough horizontal room to the ridge parent LI
    if ($ul.data('dimensions').w > (parentlioffset.left - $(document).scrollLeft())) // no room to left either?
     x = 0
    else
     x = x-$ul.data('dimensions').parentliw-$ul.data('dimensions').w
   }
   if ( parentlioffset.top+$ul.data('dimensions').h > docbottomedge ){ //if not enough vertical room to the bottom of parent LI
    if ($ul.data('dimensions').h > (parentlioffset.top - $(document).scrollTop())) // no room upwards either?
     y = $(document).scrollTop() - parentlioffset.top
    else
     y = y-$ul.data('dimensions').h+$ul.data('dimensions').parentlih
   }
  }

  $ul.css({left:x, top:y})
 },
 
 showbox:function($, $target, $flexmenu, e){
  clearTimeout($flexmenu.data('timers').hidetimer)
  $flexmenu.data('timers').showtimer=setTimeout(function(){$target.addClass('selected'); $flexmenu.show(flexdropdownmenu.animspeed)}, this.showhidedelay[0])
 },

 hidebox:function($, $target, $flexmenu){
  clearTimeout($flexmenu.data('timers').showtimer)
  $flexmenu.data('timers').hidetimer=setTimeout(function(){$target.removeClass('selected'); $flexmenu.hide(100)}, this.showhidedelay[1]) //hide flex menu plus all of its sub ULs
 },

 buildmobilemenu:function($, mainulid, $target){
  var $menu = this.ulclones[mainulid]
  function flattenuls($mainul, cloneulBol, callback, finalcall){
   var callback = callback || function(){}
   var finalcall = finalcall || function(){}
   var $headers = $mainul.find('ul').parent()
   var $mainulcopy = cloneulBol? $mainul.clone() : $mainul
   var $flattened = jQuery(document.createDocumentFragment())
   var $headers = $mainulcopy.find('ul').parent()
   for (var i=$headers.length-1; i>=0; i--){ // loop through headers backwards, so we end up with topmost UL last
    var $header = $headers.eq(i)
    var $subul = $header.find('>ul').prependTo($flattened)
    callback(i, $header, $subul)
   }
   $mainulcopy.prependTo($flattened) // Add top most UL to collection
   finalcall($mainulcopy)
   return $flattened
  }
  var $flattened = flattenuls($menu, false,
   function(i, $header, $subul){
    var $breadcrumb = $('<li class="breadcrumb" />')
     .html('<img src="' + flexdropdownmenu.backarrowpath + '" class="backarrow" />' + $header.text())
     .prependTo($subul)
    $subul.css({display:'block', left:0, top:0})
    $header.find('a:eq(0)').append('<img src="' + flexdropdownmenu.arrowpath +'" class="rightarrow" />')
    $header.bind('click', function(e){
     $mobilecontainer.data('h', $subul.outerHeight())
     var $headermenu = $(this).parent('ul')
     $headermenu.css({zIndex: flexdropdownmenu.mobilezindex++}).animate({left:'-100%', opacity: 0}, function(){this.style.visibility='hidden'})
     $subul.css({zIndex: flexdropdownmenu.mobilezindex++, left: '100%', visibility:'visible'}).animate({left:0, opacity: 1})
     e.stopPropagation()
     e.preventDefault()
    })
    $breadcrumb.bind('click', function(e){
     var $headermenu = $header.parent('ul')
     $mobilecontainer.data('h', $headermenu.outerHeight())
     $subul.css({zIndex: flexdropdownmenu.mobilezindex++}).animate({left:'100%', opacity: 0}, function(){this.style.visibility='hidden'})
     $headermenu.css({zIndex: flexdropdownmenu.mobilezindex++, left: '-100%', visibility:'visible'}).animate({left:0, opacity: 1})
     e.stopPropagation()
     e.preventDefault()
    })
   },
   function($topul){
    $topul.removeAttr("id class").css({zIndex: flexdropdownmenu.mobilezindex++, visibility:'visible', opacity:1, left:0, top:0, display:'block'})
   }
  )

  var $mobilecontainer = $('<div class="flexmenumobile" id="' + mainulid + '-mobile"/>').append($flattened).appendTo(document.body)
  $mobilecontainer.css('display', 'block')
  $mobilecontainer.data('dimensions', {w:$mobilecontainer.outerWidth(), h:$mobilecontainer.find('ul:eq(0)').outerHeight()}) //remember mobile menu's dimensions
  $mobilecontainer.css('display', 'none')
  $mobilecontainer.bind('touchstart', function(e){
   e.stopPropagation()
  })
  this.builtflexmenuids.push(mainulid + '-mobile') //remember id of mobile flex menu that was just built

 },

 buildflexmenu:function($, $menu, $target){
  $menu.css({display:'block', visibility:'hidden', zIndex:this.startzindex}).addClass('jqflexmenu').appendTo(document.body)
  $menu.bind('mouseenter', function(){
   clearTimeout($menu.data('timers').hidetimer)
  })  
  $menu.bind('mouseleave', function(){ //hide menu when mouse moves out of it
   flexdropdownmenu.hidebox($, $target, $menu)
  })
  $menu.bind(this.hidemenuevent, function(e){ //hide menu when mouse moves out of it
   e.stopPropagation()
  })
  $menu.data('dimensions', {w:$menu.outerWidth(), h:$menu.outerHeight()}) //remember main menu's dimensions
  $menu.data('timers', {})
  var $lis=$menu.find("ul").parent() //find all LIs within menu with a sub UL
  $lis.each(function(i){
   var $li=$(this).css({zIndex: 1000+i})
   var $subul=$li.find('ul:eq(0)').css({display:'block'}) //set sub UL to "block" so we can get dimensions
   $subul.data('dimensions', {w:$subul.outerWidth(), h:$subul.outerHeight(), parentliw:this.offsetWidth, parentlih:this.offsetHeight})
   $subul.data('$parentliref', $li) //cache parent LI of each sub UL
   $subul.data('timers', {})
   $li.data('$subulref', $subul) //cache sub UL of each parent LI
   $li.children("a:eq(0)").append( //add arrow images
    '<img src="'+flexdropdownmenu.arrowpath+'" class="rightarrowclass" style="border:0;" />'
   )
   $li.bind(flexdropdownmenu.triggerevt, function(e){ //show sub UL when mouse moves over parent LI
    var $targetul=$(this).css('zIndex', ++flexdropdownmenu.startzindex).addClass("selected").data('$subulref')
    if ($targetul.queue().length<=1){ //if 1 or less queued animations
     clearTimeout($targetul.data('timers').hidetimer)
     $targetul.data('timers').showtimer=setTimeout(function(){
      flexdropdownmenu.positionul($, $targetul, e)
      $targetul.show(flexdropdownmenu.animspeed)
     }, flexdropdownmenu.showhidedelay[0])
     if (flexdropdownmenu.triggerevt=="click" && $(e.target).next('ul').length==1) //if LI being clicked on is a menu header
      return false
    }
   })

   $li.bind('mouseleave', function(e){ //hide sub UL when mouse moves out of parent LI
    var $targetul=$(this).data('$subulref')
    clearTimeout($targetul.data('timers').showtimer)
    $targetul.data('timers').hidetimer=setTimeout(function(){$targetul.hide(100).data('$parentliref').removeClass('selected')}, flexdropdownmenu.showhidedelay[1])
   })

  })
  $menu.find('ul').andSelf().css({display:'none', visibility:'visible'}) //collapse all ULs again
  this.builtflexmenuids.push($menu.get(0).id) //remember id of flex menu that was just built
 },

 

 init:function($, $target, $flexmenu){
  var mobilemenucheck = this.mobilemql.matches
  this.triggerevt=(this.ismobile)? "click" : "mouseenter"
  this.showhidedelay[0]=(this.ismobile)? 0 : this.showhidedelay[0]
  if (this.builtflexmenuids.length==0){ //only bind click event to document, create overlay div once
   $(document.body).bind(this.hidemenuevent, function(e){
    $('.jqflexmenu').find('ul').andSelf().hide()
   })
   $('<div class="flexoverlay" />')
    .bind('click', function(e){
     $('div.flexmenumobile').hide()
     $('div.flexoverlay').css('display', 'none')
    })
    .appendTo(document.body)
  }
  if ($target.parents().filter('ul.jqflexmenu').length>0) //if $target matches an element within the flex menu markup, don't bind onflexmenu to that element
   return
  if (!mobilemenucheck){ // if REGULAR MENU MODE (non mobile)
   if (!this.ulclones[$flexmenu.get(0).id]) // if drop down menu hasn't been cloned yet (for mobile menu usage)
    this.ulclones[$flexmenu.get(0).id] = $flexmenu.clone()
   $('div.flexmenumobile').css('display', 'none')
   $('div.flexoverlay').css('display', 'none')   
   if (jQuery.inArray($flexmenu.get(0).id, this.builtflexmenuids)==-1){ //if this flex menu hasn't been built yet
    this.buildflexmenu($, $flexmenu, $target)
   }
   if (!$target.data('setting')){ // if this $target doesn't have a regular flex menu associated with it yet
    var useroffsets=$target.attr('data-offsets')? $target.attr('data-offsets').split(',') : [0,0] //get additional user offsets of menu
    useroffsets=[parseInt(useroffsets[0]), parseInt(useroffsets[1])]
    $target.data('setting', {dir: $target.attr('data-dir'), useroffsets: useroffsets}) //store direction (drop right or down) of menu plus user offsets
    $target.bind(flexdropdownmenu.triggerevt, function(e){
     if (!flexdropdownmenu.mobilemql.matches){ // if not in mobile menu mode
      $flexmenu.css('zIndex', ++flexdropdownmenu.startzindex)
      flexdropdownmenu.positionul($, $flexmenu, e, $target)
      flexdropdownmenu.showbox($, $target, $flexmenu, e)
      if (flexdropdownmenu.triggerevt=="click")
       e.preventDefault()
     }
    })
    $target.bind("mouseleave", function(e){
     if (!flexdropdownmenu.mobilemql.matches){ // if not in mobile menu mode
      flexdropdownmenu.hidebox($, $target, $flexmenu)
      e.preventDefault()
     }
    })
   }
  }
  else{ // if MOBILE MENU MODE
   if (!this.ulclones[$flexmenu.get(0).id]) // if drop down menu hasn't been cloned yet (for mobile menu usage)
    this.ulclones[$flexmenu.get(0).id] = $flexmenu.clone()
   $('.jqflexmenu').find('ul').andSelf().hide()
    if (jQuery.inArray($flexmenu.get(0).id + '-mobile', this.builtflexmenuids)==-1){ //if this mobile flex menu hasn't been built yet
     this.buildmobilemenu($, $flexmenu.get(0).id, $target)
    }
    var $mobilemenu = $('div#' + $flexmenu.get(0).id + '-mobile')
    if (!$target.data('mobilesetting')){ // if this $target doesn't have a regular flex menu associated with it yet
     $target.data('mobilesetting', {dir: $target.attr('data-dir'), useroffsets: [0,0]}) 
     $target.bind('click', function(e){
      if (flexdropdownmenu.mobilemql.matches){ // if in mobile menu mode
       $('div.flexoverlay').css('display', 'block')
       var winwidth = $(window).width()
       var winheight = $(window).height()
       var marginLeft = (winwidth/2 - $mobilemenu.data('dimensions').w/2 < 0)? -winwidth/2 : -$mobilemenu.data('dimensions').w/2
       var marginTop = (winheight/2 - $mobilemenu.data('dimensions').h/2 < 0)? -winheight/2 : -$mobilemenu.data('dimensions').h/2
       $mobilemenu.css({left:'50%', top:'50%', marginLeft: marginLeft, marginTop: marginTop})
       $mobilemenu.css({zIndex: flexdropdownmenu.mobilezindex++, display:'block'})
       return false
      }
     })
    }

  }
 }
}

jQuery.fn.addflexmenu=function(flexmenuid, options){
 var $=jQuery
 flexdropdownmenu.mobilemql = (window.matchMedia)? window.matchMedia(flexdropdownmenu.mobilemediaquery) : {matches: false, addListener: function(){}}
 return this.each(function(){ //return jQuery obj
  var $target=$(this)
  if (typeof options=="object"){ //if options parameter defined
   if (options.dir)
    $target.attr('data-dir', options.dir) //set/overwrite data-dir attr with defined value
   if (options.offsets)
    $target.attr('data-offsets', options.offsets) //set/overwrite data-offsets attr with defined value
  }
  if ($('#'+flexmenuid).length==1){ //check flex menu is defined
   flexdropdownmenu.init($, $target, $('#'+flexmenuid))
   if (window.matchMedia){
    window.matchMedia(flexdropdownmenu.mobilemediaquery).addListener(function(){
     flexdropdownmenu.init($, $target, $('#'+flexmenuid))
    })
   }
  }
 })
};

//By default, add flex menu to anchor links with attribute "data-flexmenu"
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 var $anchors=$('*[data-flexmenu]')
 $anchors.each(function(){
  $(this).addflexmenu(this.getAttribute('data-flexmenu'))
 })
})


//ddlistmenu: Function to define a UL list menu dynamically

function ddlistmenu(id, className){
 var menu=document.createElement('ul')
 if (id)
  menu.id=id
 if (className)
  menu.className=className
 this.menu=menu
}

ddlistmenu.prototype={
 addItem:function(url, text, target){
  var li=document.createElement('li')
  li.innerHTML='<a href="'+url+'" target="'+target+'">'+text+'</a>'
  this.menu.appendChild(li)
  this.li=li
  return this
 },
 addSubMenu:function(){
  var s=new ddlistmenu(null, null)
  this.li.appendChild(s.menu)
  return s

 }
}
```

```css
.flexdropdownmenu, .flexdropdownmenu ul{ /*topmost and sub ULs, respectively*/
font: normal 13px Verdana;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 0;
list-style-type: none;
background: white;
border: 1px solid black;
border-bottom-width: 0;
visibility: hidden;
display: none; /*collapse all sub menus to begin with*/
box-shadow: 3px 3px 8px #818181; /*shadow for CSS3 capable browsers.*/
-webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 8px #818181;
-moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 8px #818181;
}


.flexdropdownmenu li{
position: relative;
}

.flexdropdownmenu li a{
display: block;
width: 160px; /*width of menu (not including side paddings)*/
color: black;
background: #dddddd;
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 4px 5px;
}

* html .flexdropdownmenu li{ /*IE6 CSS hack*/
display: inline-block;
width: 170px; /*width of menu (include side paddings of LI A*/
}

.flexdropdownmenu li a:hover, .flexdropdownmenu li.selected>a{
background: #cecfce;
}

.rightarrowclass{
position: absolute;
top: 6px;
right: 5px;
}


/* ######### CSS for shadow added to sub menus  ######### */

.ddshadow{ 
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 0;
height: 0;
background-color: #ccc; /* generally should be just a little lighter than the box-shadow color for CSS3 capable browsers */
}

.toplevelshadow{
margin: 5px 0 0 5px; /* in NON CSS3 capable browsers gives the offset of the shadow */
opacity: 0.8; /* shadow opacity mostly for NON CSS3 capable browsers. Doesn't work in IE */
}

.ddcss3support .ddshadow.toplevelshadow {
margin: 0; /* in CSS3 capable browsers overrides offset from NON CSS3 capable browsers, allowing the box-shadow values in the next selector to govern that */
/* opacity: 1; */ /* optionally uncomment this to remove partial opacity for browsers supporting a box-shadow property which has its own slight gradient opacity */
}

.ddcss3support .ddshadow {
background-color: transparent;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #aaa; /* box-shadow color generally should be a little darker than that for the NON CSS3 capable browsers background-color */
-moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #aaa;
-webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #aaa;
}

/* ######### Mobile menu container CSS ######### */

div.flexoverlay{ /* overlay that covers page when mobile menu is shown */
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
left: 0;
top: 0;
position: fixed;
background: black;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
opacity: 0.7;
z-index: 1000; /* z-index value should be smaller than  mobilezindex: 1001 variable inside flexdropdown.js */
display: none;
}

div.flexmenumobile{ /* main mobile menu container */
position: fixed;
color: white;
width: 250px; /* width of mobile menu */
display: none;
}

div.flexmenumobile a{
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
}


div.flexmenumobile ul{ /* style for all ULs in general inside mobile menu */
list-style: none;
width: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background: white;
border: 1px solid black;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
opacity: 0;
visibility: hidden;
}



div.flexmenumobile ul li{
border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
position: relative;
font-weight: bold;
}

div.flexmenumobile ul li.breadcrumb{ /* breadcrumb LI that's added to the top of every sub level UL */
cursor: pointer;
padding: 8px;
padding-left: 5px;
background: gray;
font-size: 1.1em;
}

div.flexmenumobile ul li a{
display: block;
color: black;
background: #fae7a9;
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
padding: 6px;
font-size: 1.1em;
}

div.flexmenumobile ul li a:hover{
background: #F0CE7D;
}

div.flexmenumobile ul img.backarrow{
margin-right: 5px;
}

div.flexmenumobile ul img.rightarrow{
position: absolute;
right: 5px;
top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="flexdropdown.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="flexdropdown.js">

/***********************************************
* Flex Level Drop Down Menu- (c) Dynamic Drive DHTML code library (www.dynamicdrive.com)
* Please keep this notice intact
* Visit Dynamic Drive at http://www.dynamicdrive.com/ for this script and 100s more
***********************************************/

</script>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Drop Down Menu:</h3>
<p style="text-align:left"><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com" data-flexmenu="flexmenu1"><img src="Teams_Bar_New.jpg" alt="Mountain View" style="width:175px;height:29px;"/></a></p>

<h3>Drop to the right, with custom offset of 8px horizontally, 0px vertically, added:</h3>
<p style="text-align:left"><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com" data-flexmenu="flexmenu2" data-dir="h" data-offsets="8,0">Webmaster Resources</a></p>


<!--HTML for Flex Drop Down Menu 1-->
<ul id="flexmenu1" class="flexdropdownmenu">
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">CIS</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Finance</a>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3.1a</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3.2a</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3.3a</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3.4a</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Human Resources</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Legal</a>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Sub Item 5.1a</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Item Folder 5.2a</a>
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Item 5.2.1a</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Item 5.2.2a</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Item 5.2.3a</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Item 5.2.4a</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Marketing</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Support Services</a></li>
</ul>


<!--HTML for Flex Drop Down Menu 2-->
<ul id="flexmenu2" class="flexdropdownmenu">
<li><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/">Dynamic Drive</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.cssdrive.com">CSS Drive</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com">JavaScript Kit</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.codingforums.com">Coding Forums</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/">DOM Reference</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anybody please suggest how to fix this issue. I need my dropdown just below the hover image, not left of that image.

The above HTML, CSS, and jQuery code can also be found in the below link:

http://dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/flexdropdown_suppliment.htm