# negative property values reflecting in Firefox & IE but not in chrome

Tags: css

In my CSS i m defining minus values for some properties and that minus values is reflecting in my firefox and internet explorer browser but minus values are not reflecting for my chrome browser .so can anybody suggest me how fix this issue.please check below is the code.

```css
.flexdropdownmenu li a{
display: block;
width: 160px; /*width of menu (not including side paddings)*/
color: black;
background: #dddddd;
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 4px 5px;
margin-left:-25px;
 
}
```

Here in margin-left property i have given negative values.

thanks in advance

Comment: Please can you create an [MCVE] as with the code you have supplied we will have no clue as to why it is not working

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40372673/dropdown-on-hover-is-moving-towards-left-of-dropdown-image-in-jquery                                                      .hi, this is a reference to my previous post and in .flexdropdownmenu li a{ }  class in my previous post der was no negative value but to fix the same issue in my previous post i have provided negative value.

Comment: Have you clicked the link in my comment? You still haven't created that in your last question and I wouldn't call all that code minimal or verifiable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is fixed in chrome version  54.0.2840.71 the cookies were not getting refreshed so i was facing the above issue then after referring the below link

[Chrome not loading new styles after css update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40383732/chrome-not-loading-new-styles-after-css-update)

after a hard refresh using (Ctrl+Shift+R).my css changes are also reflecting in chrome which is negative values . hence problem fixed.